# Linq to sql How to select elements from a list

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have two classes:

```
public class Artikel
{
   int id{get;set;};
   string name{get;set;};
}    

public class NewArtikel
{
    int id{get;set;};
    List<Artikel> artikels{get;set;};
}
```

Now, I have a list of the second class

```
List<NewArtikel> myList = new List<NewArtikel>()
```

Is there are any posibility in LINQ to SQL to select all elements from myList with the needed Artikel.name

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

```
var allRequiredArtikels = myList.SelectMany(n => n.artikels)
    .Where(a => a.name == "requiredName");
```

The [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) flattens all `Artikel`s from all the `NewArtikel` elements, then the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) filters them by `name`.

---

Okay so, if you want the `NewArtikel`s that have an `Artikel` with the required name you could do.

```
var newArtikels = myList.Where(n => n.artikels
    .Any(a => a.name == "requiredName"));
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but if I need to have result in the list type List<NewArtikel>

Comment: @MoraruViorel, I've edited my answer on the assumption that `NewArtikel` does not have a `name` property, is this correct? Or, are we missing some inheritance in the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
List<NewArtikel> myFinalList = (from artikel in myList.artikels where artikel.name =   "requiredName"
select new NewArtikel(){
Id= artikel.Id

}).ToList();
```